# Redirecting URL with query string?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am bad at using htaccess files and didn't find anything on google that would work for me.

Currently my htaccess file can redirect me from `index.php?page=$1/` where $1 is the page name for example `/page/profile`.

However I want to pass a query after the URL to see other users profile by opening `/page/profile/1` or `/page/profile?id=1` either one is fine.

This is my index.php file:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
switch ($_GET['page'])
{
    case 'home':
        require_once("includes/header.php");
        require_once("pages/index.php");
        require_once("includes/footer.php");
        break;
    case 'profile':
        require_once("includes/header.php");
        require_once("pages/profile.php");
        require_once("includes/footer.php");    
        break;
    case 'logout':
        require_once("pages/logout.php");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another one!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&profile=$2 [L]
```

This should do it.

**EDIT :**
You should use this instead :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/profile/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=profile&profile=$1 [NC,L]
```

The new code will only accept the parameter on `profile` page. and the `NC` tag was used to indicate a No Case Sensitive system so it won't generate 404 when acessing `/proFile` instead of `profile` (Remove the NC tag to use Case Sensitive).
The new code also only accepts letters a-Z and Numbers, `-` and `_`. This should prevent some injection. Replace `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)` with `([^/\.]+)` to accept anything.
The new code also only accepts numbers in the profile parameter.

Comment: No, with this when I go to /page/profile/1 it shows me a 404 error.

Comment: Hi, I got this : https://image.ibb.co/i97ZDe/image.png when accessing `http://domain/page/test/1`.